# save images from plist to gallery

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

plist file is stored in which pictures are displayed in scroll-view, made ​​button "save", need help with the code. PLEASE!!

to do so, that would "save" button, save pictures in which I am. For example: I'm on the picture number 5, touch "save" and picture number 5 save to the gallery, I'm on the picture number 21, touch "save" and picture number 21 save to the gallery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create some photo gallery apps, check out this open source [sample](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser).

Created by Michael Waterfall, which includes photo gallery from images stored on server or locally.

Download the plist from server & provide the urls to the gallery app in the required format, then show the gallery view as given in sample.

In order to save the image to users photo album, in the sample code the class `PhotoBrowserController` handles the gallery task, which has the indexes of the photos next, current, previous.

Using the image get the image from saved cache and save it to users photo album using

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage,self,nil,nil);`

Look at the sample app & go through the flow you will come to know how can modify for your requirements.